# Why do we trust credibility intervals to contain the true parameter?

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, frequentist, credible-interval

I understand confidence intervals and to what extent they can be trusted (and why).

However, I’m not so sure how to motivate why I should trust credibility intervals except insofar as they can also claim good pre-data probability of containing the true parameter.

So, to the Bayesian folks — how do you convince yourself that, say, 99% credibility intervals are sufficient to bracket the true parameter in the vast majority of cases?

Note: I’m asking this from a viewpoint of a frequentist view of probability and that all models should be verifiable/testable.

Comment: You can investigate the frequentist operating characteristics of the Bayesian inference machine; however, the Bayesian interpretation of probability is that it measures the belief of the experimenter.  This inherently makes Bayesian models unverifiable/untestable.  The justification I most often hear from Bayesians for justifying their intervals is that with increasing sample size they are dominated by the likelihood and converge to the unknown fixed true parameter value.  Of course the long-run and asymptotic properties of the likelihood are not a consequence of the Bayesian paradigm.

Comment: @Geoffrey How does the conclusion of "unverifiable/untestable" logically follow from an assertion about how someone might be interpreting probability? If I am handed a model by someone then, regardless of what their mental state might be, if the model is sufficiently quantitative and documented, I can at least in principle conceive of testing it.

Comment: @whuber, verifiable does not mean the results can be QC'ed.  Anyone can QC a Bayesian model.  If I make a claim about the bias of a coin or the operating characteristics of a cancer screening test, not only can any calculation of mine be QC'ed it can be verified within a margin of error through repeated sampling.  There is a right answer that exists outside of my opinion.  A Bayesian posterior probability is not a verifiable claim about the actual parameter the hypothesis nor the experiment.  To "verify" a Bayesian probability one need only ask the experimenter if it reflects his beliefs.

Comment: I would recommend a review of recent literature about what Bayesians really think.  The Gelman *et al.* text would be a good entry point.  As I recall, one of its concerns is to address this issue of the objectivity (or lack thereof) of a Bayesian analysis.  I think almost all practicing statisticians are obliged to reject your interpretation, because we believe we are doing more than psychological analysis of individual experimenters!